# UEM - How to add dynamic values in App Configuration

Tags: blackberry

Where could we add dynamic values in UEM and pass it to the app? I know static values could be added in policy XML.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean using dynamic values in the application configuration for a specific app? These are shown if you open the app from the apps list in BlackBerry UEM and then click on an item in the App configuration table.  If so, the answer is no. Dynamic values are not supported in app configurations.

BlackBerry UEM does support dynamic variables for some other areas. You can use variables in profiles, compliance notifications, activation emails, and event notifications. For more information on these, refer to this document: https://docs.blackberry.com/en/endpoint-management/blackberry-uem/12_11/administration/profiles-variables-email-templates/variables

Comment: For example if i set default variable.. %EmailAddressDomain% as value in App Configuration I receive it as "%EmailAddressDomain%" in the app. I need the actual value for it. What does the "%" mean then? I suppose it should give me the value.

Comment: Am using  UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "com.apple.configuration.managed") to fetch the variable. This returns nil.

Comment: Do you have a solution for this

Comment: Wildcards in App Config variables are not currently supported in BlackBerry UEM.  You can refer to the doc I linked to above for a list of configurable items where BlackBerry UEM does support wild cards.